# How to configure SharePoint 2013 in Azure

Tags: azure, configuration-wizard

I had two Virtual machines in Azure. One Having SharePoint and the other is for SQLServer Database. I got credentials for Remote Desktop Connection for both machines.

At the configuration stage for SharePoint, a wizard is open , it demands database credentials, when I put credentials of database into wizard and click on "NEXT" button it shows error.[image]

Comment: Does the error popup almost immediately or it spins a while before it shows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's giving you an error regarding the database itself, not the credentials, make sure that the name of the database server is correct, if you have an instance, you need to provide the instance name. Make sure that the SharePoint server (the server you're working on right now) can ping and connect to SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check couple of things.

- Account you mentioned in that screen, Should have DB creator and Secuirty Admin rights.
- If you login with different account then the one you mentioned, Make sure that account should have same permission.
- Make sure You can access the SQL server from this server. may be use FQDN server url

are you using SQL account or Domain account?

Answer (score 0):

Before trying to set up the sharepoint farm, have you done basic config/testing, such as ensuring the two VMs can communicate? Are they on the same virtual network? Also, you mentioned the two machines, but what about a DC for accounts?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that port 1433 (or whatever port you are using for SQL) is open on the SQL server and if not create a new rule:

From the SQL server:

Launch "Windows Firewall with Advanced Security"

Click "Inbound Rules" then "New Rule..."
Click Port, then Next

Type your port number in "Specified Local Ports" then Next.

Click Next 3 times, then give the rule a name and an optional description.

Click Finish